# How to single bind in ui-sref?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angularjs-routing

I am doing `ng-repeat` of a list that look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in myCtrl.data" ui-sref="app.detail({id: x.id})">
    <img ng-src="{{::x.image}}">
    <h2>{{::x.name | characters:35}}</h2>
</div>
```

When I monitor the watcher, I found that the watcher increases when the list getting longer. If I remove the `{id: x.id}` from the `ui-sref`, no matter how long the list is, the number of watcher  always remains the same.

So, my question is how can I do a single binding in `ui-sref`?

Comment: What do you mean by **how can I do single binding in `ui-sref`**?

Comment: @PankajParkar If there is `{id: x.id}` in the `ui-sref`, the watcher increases as the list getting longer. It is just like `{{x.image}}` will get watcher increases, but if `{{::x.image}}` no increases in watcher. That's what I mean with `single binding` here. So, how can I avoid it with `ui-sref`?

Comment: could you look at the way I suggested..?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1599#issuecomment-156730521

Answer (score 3):

```
ui-sref="app.detail(::{id: x.id})
```

**no redirects nothing, one line code  one time binding**

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, if you look at API you will come to know that, it adds watcher
>   from [**this line**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/a7d25c6/src/stateDirectives.js#L123) & you can't avoid that.

You could get rid of that watcher by do the redirection to state thing by your own, like you could have `ng-click="redirect('app.detail', {id: x.id})"` event there instead of having `ui-sref` directive, and from `redirect` method you could redirect to the state using `$state.go`.

**Code**

```
$scope.redirect = function(stateName, param){
    $state.go(stateName, param)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that it can be done pretty easy. That is by `ui-sref="app.detail({id: {{::x.id}}})"`.

Comment: Yeah, I am monitoring the watcher in Chrome using Angular watchers plugin. From there I can see that if I am doing this way, the number of watcher always remain the same even when the list getting longer.

Comment: Thats cool..could you add that as an answer..or feel free to edit mine.

Comment: @user1995781 `ui-sref="app.detail({id: {{::x.id}}})"` gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @user1995781 it should be `ui-sref="app.detail({id: x.id})`